# When minimized into the system tray, a WPF Window does not respond to message from PostMessage from the other instance when

Tags: wpf

I am working on a task to restore and maximize a window from system tray when the second instance of the same application starts.

When the 2nd instance starts and fail to grab the mutex. It calls the following code to signal the first instance to show itself:

```
public static void ShowFirstInstance()

  {
     WinApi.PostMessage(
        (IntPtr)WinApi.HWND_BROADCAST, 
        WM_SHOWFIRSTINSTANCE, 
        IntPtr.Zero, 
        IntPtr.Zero);
  }
```

The message is registered using the following:

```
public static readonly int WM_SHOWFIRSTINSTANCE =
         WinApi.RegisterWindowMessage("WM_SHOWFIRSTINSTANCE|{0}", 250);
```

I have following in the code behind of the window to catch the message and show the window:

```
private IntPtr WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled)
      {
         if (msg == SingleInstance.WM_SHOWFIRSTINSTANCE)
         {
             WinApi.ShowToFront(hwnd);
         }

         return IntPtr.Zero;
      }
```

When I test it out. Whenever the first instance hide in the system tray, the message never caught. Do I miss anything?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I've done this in the past:

App.xaml.cs:

```
private static readonly Mutex Mutex = new Mutex(true, "{" + YourGuidHere + "}");

//return true if other instance is open, allowing for UI cleanup/suspension while shutdown() is completed
private bool EnforceSingleInstance()
{
    //try...catch provides safety for if the other instance is closed during Mutex wait
    try
    {
        if (!Mutex.WaitOne(TimeSpan.Zero, true))
        {
            var currentProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess();

            var runningProcess =
                Process.GetProcesses().Where(
                    p =>
                    p.Id != currentProcess.Id &&
                    p.ProcessName.Equals(currentProcess.ProcessName, StringComparison.Ordinal)).FirstOrDefault();

            if (runningProcess != null)
            {
                WindowFunctions.RestoreWindow(runningProcess.MainWindowHandle);

                Shutdown();
                return true;
            }
        }

        Mutex.ReleaseMutex();
    }
    catch (AbandonedMutexException ex)
    {
        //do nothing, other instance was closed so we may continue
    }
    return false;
}
```

WindowFunctions:

```
//for enum values, see http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Enums.WindowsMessages
public enum WM : uint
{
    ...
    SYSCOMMAND = 0x0112,
    ...
}

//for message explanation, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646360(v=vs.85).aspx
private const int SC_RESTORE = 0xF120;

public static void RestoreWindow(IntPtr hWnd)
{
    if (hWnd.Equals(0))
        return;

    SendMessage(hWnd,
                (uint)WM.SYSCOMMAND,
                SC_RESTORE,
                0);
}

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd,
                                        uint msg,
                                        uint wParam,
                                        uint lParam);
```

Comment: on my tests, `runningProcess.MainWindowHandle` is IntPtr.Zero while minimized.

Comment: @itsho, not sure why that would be. `currentProcess.MainWindowHandle` could be zero depending on when you run the code, but currentProcess should still have a handle. 
This is tricky to debug in VS since you can only run one debug session at a time in a given session, which will have a different process id than if you run the exe outside of visual studio.
Try adding `MessageBox.Show("My handle: " + currentProcess.MainWindowHandle + " Existing handle: " + runningProcess.MainWindowHandle);` just before the call to `RestoreWindow()` and run it outside of VS.